# Removing a line based in a criteria

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I just want to delete the line which contain the number of selected rows in a query. I mean the one in the last line. please help.

```
[root@machine-test scripts]# ./hit_ratio.sh 
     193830           432           
     185260           125

2 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know you want to delete the last line, but not other lines which contain similar text, or you don't know what text it will contain, `sed` is uniquely suitable.

```
./hit_ratio.sh | sed '$d'
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the power of `sed` or the super-powers of `awk` if all you want is to delete a line based on a pattern. You can use:

```
./hit_ratio.sh | grep -v ' rows selected.'
```

You *can* do it with `awk` and `sed` but it's a bit like trying to kill a fly with a thermo-nuclear warhead:

```
pax> ./hit_ratio.sh  | sed '/ rows selected./d'
     193830           432           
 185260           125
pax> ./hit_ratio.sh  | awk '$2!="rows"{print}'
     193830           432           
 185260           125
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, do something with your SQL script. Sometimes, turning on the `set nocount on` statement eliminates the "rows affected" line.

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation is not to have that line outputted, list hit_ratio.sh here maybe it can be modified not to output that line

Anyway if you have to remove **only** the last line the easiest would be to use head:

```
./hit_ratio.sh  | head -n -1
```

Using -n and a negative number, makes head print all but the last N lines of the input

Comment: That's not portable; not all head(1) implementations have this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `head` to get the first `N - 1` lines of your file, where N is the length of the file (calculated with `wc -l`)

`head -n $(($(cat lipsum.log | wc -l) - 1)) lipsum.log` works

Answer (score 0):

Pipe through

```
sed -e '/\w*[0-9]\+ rows\? selected/d'
```